# My word search game game keeps crashing but no error detected when i am building it

Tags: java, kotlin, game-development, wordsearch

I know this may be too general and seems like a question of a fool. I am having trouble with the game i am developing and I can't seem to find what's wrong. I'll try to describe this as easy as possible

So I am creating a word search game with multiple stages. There's the opening page, level map, and in that are buttons where the user can click and the word search game will be present.

the problem is, the moment I click the level 1 button (which currently is the only button working), the app crashes. There was no error detected when I was building it and it installed quickly on the device.

what could be the possible problem?

For reference, this is my files
https://github.com/mpdc2510/JavaProject

[EDIT] okay, I followed the steps to debug and this error showed

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.javaproject, PID: 12835
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.javaproject/com.example.javaproject.LondonLevel1}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: congrats_layout must not be null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3410)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2017)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: congrats_layout must not be null
        at com.example.javaproject.LondonLevel1.onCreate(LondonLevel1.kt:36)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1300)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3410) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2017) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12835 SIG: 9
```

Comment: you should add at least the error thrown that causes this situation

Comment: hello. I can't see any error thrown upon building the app. i am running the app on real device so as soon as the installation is finished, I just tried to click the buttons.

Comment: A runtime error is not the same as a compilation error. Lack of compilation errors only guarantees that your program is syntactically correct, not that it won't crash.

Comment: And please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question. You can't expect us to comb through your code to find a problem, especially since there's no code in the link you gave.

Comment: I'm sorry for that. kindly visit the link again, i uploaded the class files as well as the layouts

Comment: Oh, kotlin, I didn't see the tag earlier. Sorry, I don't know the language, can't help. Still, the information to reproduce the problem should be *in the question*, not in an external link.

Comment: Also, is this running on android? Does the log say anything? If you want help you'll have to show some effort.

Comment: yes, this is running on a real android device

Comment: Filter logcat for "ERROR" or "WARNING" and post what is shown.

Answer (score 0):

In your `LondonLevel` class you're calling `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` which looks to be the wrong layout.  `activity_main` has no `congrats_layout` id.  Probably a mistake where you wanted `setContentView(R.layout.activity_level_map)`